# CKFinder to work cross-sub domain

Tags: cross-domain, ckfinder

CK finder is not working for cross domain. what should i do to enable/configure for this cross domain support?.

Answer (score 2):

it is not possible due to security

this is they response in the faq :

> Can CKFinder and CKEditor be located on different domains?
>
> Cross-domain file management between CKEditor and CKFinder is
>   impossible.

http://ckeditor.com/support/faq/ckfinder#question5